# How to restart an view without losing data

Tags: android, forms, kotlin, themes, android-darkmode

I am working on an App to digitize old forms in my company. Every form has many input values (RadioGroups, EditText, Checkboxes). The App needs a dynamic dark mode, orientated by sunrise and sunset. So, when I worked in a form, it should change the App-Theme if the sun has set.

My Local Broadcast Service (started by MainActivity) checks, if the actual time is between sunset and sunrise and sends a broadcast. The foreground activity receives the broadcast and should change the theme to dark, but without losing the input values.

Everything I tried doesn't work, because I act in the Receiver function and set the ContentView in the onCreate-Method:

```
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark)
        application.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark)
        theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme_Dark, true)
        findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).invalidate()
```

It's very important, that I don't lose the values in the inputs, so I can't use `startActivity(intent)` & `finish()` and `recreate()`.

Does anybody know a solution to the problem?

Comment: `recreate()` doesn't cause your views to lose any state.

Comment: Jear, its real. Its only lost datas in a RecyclerView after adding a new entry via Dialog. But that doesnt hurt. Thank you very much!